# DataContractJsonSerializer - Deserializing DateTime within List<object>

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm having trouble using the [`System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class to deserialize DateTime instances contained within a `List<object>`. I cannot seem to get DateTime to deserialize back into the original type. The `DataContractJsonSerializer` always deserializes it into a string type with the format `"/Date(1329159196126-0500)/"`. It'll serialize and deserialize fine if I run it through using a strongly typed `List<DateTime>`, however I am looking for  way to get the serializer to identify and properly deserialize DateTimes when encountered within a simple list or array of `object`.

Note that DateTimes are the only type besides primitives and strings that this list will ever contain.
Here is the code snippet I'm using to test this.

```
var list = new List<object> { 27, "foo bar", 12.34m, true, DateTime.Now };
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (List<object>));
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, list);
    ms.Position = 0;
    var deserializedList = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as List<object>;
}
```

Comment: You should think about changing the accepted answer to the one with 40 upvotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems like very strange behavior, my guess is that it stems from DateTime not being a type that is recongnized in JSON. However, you can roll your own IDataContractSurrogate to modify the serialization/deserialization process.

To use this modify your sample code when you create the the serializer to this:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<object>), null, int.MaxValue, false, new DateTimeDataContractSurrogate(), true);
```

Then add this class:

```
public class DateTimeDataContractSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
    {
        private static readonly Regex dateRegex = new Regex(@"/Date\((\d+)([-+])(\d+)\)/");
        private static readonly DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
        {
            // not used
            return null;
        }

        public object GetCustomDataToExport(System.Reflection.MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
        {
            // not used
            return null;
        }

        public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
        {
            // not used
            return type;
        }

        public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
        {
            // for debugging
            //Console.WriteLine("GetDeserializedObject: obj = {0} ({1}), targetType = {2}", obj, obj.GetType(), targetType);

            // only act on List<object> types
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof(List<object>))
            {
                var objList = (List<object>)obj;

                List<object> copyList = new List<object>(); // a list to copy values into. this will be the list returned.
                foreach (var item in objList)
                {
                    string s = item as string;
                    if (s != null)
                    {
                        // check if we match the DateTime format
                        Match match = dateRegex.Match(s);
                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            // try to parse the string into a long. then create a datetime and convert to local time.
                            long msFromEpoch;
                            if (long.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out msFromEpoch))
                            {
                                TimeSpan fromEpoch = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(msFromEpoch);
                                copyList.Add(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(epoch.Add(fromEpoch), TimeZoneInfo.Local));
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    copyList.Add(item); // add unmodified
                }

                return copyList;
            }

            return obj;
        }

        public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
        {
            // not used   
        }

        public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
        {
            // for debugging
            //Console.WriteLine("GetObjectToSerialize: obj = {0} ({1}), targetType = {2}", obj, obj.GetType(), targetType);
            return obj;
        }

        public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
        {
            // not used
            return null;
        }

        public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
        {
            // not used
            return typeDeclaration;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is essentially the solution I ended up implementing. Thanks.

Comment: In order to support dates before 1970 your regex should be `/Date\((-?\d+)([-+])(\d+)\)/)`

Comment: This Regex fails when the Date is without time zone. I ended up using `new Regex(@"/Date\((\d+)([-+])?(\d+)?\)/")`

Answer (score 45):

In the .NET Framework version 4.5 the `DataContractJsonSerializer` has a constructor that accepts a `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` object that can be used to set the `DateTimeFormat`:

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CreateOmsEntryCommand),
              new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
              {
                  DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
              });
```

Comment: In terms of serialisation, this doesn't seem to work if the `DateTime` is not in UTC in the first place: it will have the values of the local time, but with the `Z` representing UTC (so be misinterpreted on the reading side). It's probably better to use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK` instead.

Comment: I agree, use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK` or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz`. Don't use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`.

Answer (score 5):

If `DataContractJsonSerializer` isn't a *must*, here is a solution using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/).

```
var list = new List<object> { 27, "foo bar", 12.34m, true, DateTime.Now };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
var orgObj=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(json);
```

This is the Json string

```
[27,"foo bar",12.34,true,"\/Date(1329161615596+0200)\/"]
```

and returned types are `long`,`string`,`double`,`bool` and `DateTime`

Answer (score 4):

You could convert *DateTime.Now* to a string before serialization and
convert it back to *DateTime* after deserialization.

Conversion to string by:

```
string dateAsString = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
```

Conversion back to DateTime after deserialization:

```
DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(deserializedList[4]);
```

So the whole code would be like:

```
  string dateAsString = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
  var list = new object[] { 27, "foo bar", 12.34m, true, dateAsString };

  var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (List<object>));

  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, list);
    ms.Position = 0;
    var deserializedList = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as List<object>;
    DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(deserializedList[4]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the issue is to use `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` to change the `DateTimeFormat` to [`round trip o`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) so that everything is preserved and then it will successfully convert.

Tested with `Local` and `Utc`

```cs
        public DataContractJsonSerializerSettings DataContractJsonSerializerSettings = new()
        {
            DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK"),
            SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true,
            EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.Never,
            UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true,
            IgnoreExtensionDataObject = true,
        };
```