# Json DateTime serialization is different in DataContractJsonSerializer and System.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

How can I force [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) to accept [System.Json](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Json) DateTime serialization format (ISO 8601) ?

The problem is that System.Json output "2012-03-01T16:24:55.000" format but DataContractJsonSerializer need "/Date(1329161615596+0200)/" format.

I have this error :
There was an error deserializing the object of type xyz. DateTime content '2012-03-01T16:24:55.000' does not start with '/Date(' and end with ')/' as required for JSON.

Comment: You can't force to it to accept anything, but you can convert it to match it.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I think that it also has something to do with conversion to/from Epoch time. I've messed with similar before but since you have no code and I haven't worked with the two classes you're mentioning, I can't really help much further but I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you Aske. Now when working with System.Json I no longer use the default serializer but I convert the DateTime to "/Date(" + EpochDateTime + ")/" string. It solves my problem for now I think.

Comment: Check out the solutions for this question similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266435/datacontractjsonserializer-deserializing-datetime-within-listobject

Comment: May [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) treats it differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an adapter class which pre-processes your serialized data during deserialization, and plumbs all other functions through to the sealed `DataContractJsonSerializer` class.

```
public class DataContractSystemJsonSerializer : XmlObjectSerializer
{

    protected DataContractJsonSerializer innerSerializer;


    public DataContractSystemJsonSerializer(Type t)
    {
        this.innerSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer (t);
    }
    ...

    public override Object ReadObject(Stream stream)
    {
        Object obj = null;
        MemoryStream out = new MemoryStream();
        Byte[] buf = new Byte[64];
        stream.Read(buf,0,64);

        int i = 0;
        while(stream.Read(buf,i,1))
        {
          convertDatesInBuffer(&buf, &i);              

          out.write(buf, i, 1);

          i = (i+1)%64;
        }

        return innerSerializer.ReadObject(out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks kb0 but now I use Json.NET everywhere !