# How to use DataContractJsonSerializer with auth token

Tags: c#, json, datacontractserializer

I have a JSON text that looks like this:

```
{
    "access_token":"really-long-string-here",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":1234567,
    "userName":"GlenH7@Foo.com",
    ".issued":"Mon, 09 Nov 2015 23:02:04 GMT",
    ".expires":"Mon, 23 Nov 2015 23:02:04 GMT"
}
```

and an `AuthToken` class that looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class AuthToken
{
    [DataMember]
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long expires_in { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime issued { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime expires { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I examine the `authToken` in the following code, the `issued` and `expires` `DateTime` values are set to the min datetime value (i.e. 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM).  The other values come back as expected, and the authorization attempt was successful.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/MyAuthPath", authContent);
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AuthToken));
Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
AuthToken authToken = (AuthToken)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
```

---

My suspicion is that because of the mismatch in variable names (`.expires` vs `expires`) that the JSON serializer isn't able to parse those fields.  Specifically, the dot or period in the `.expires` is throwing things off.

What I'd like to do is take the `.expires` value from the JSON text and use that within my application to keep track of when the token expires.  If the token has expired, I want to automatically request a new token before making my other web service calls.

I can't name `AuthToken.expires` as `.expires` as that's invalid syntax within C#.

How can I extract the `.expires` information from the returned JSON object?  My preference would be to have the `DataContractJsonSerializer` handle this automatically for me, but I'm open to alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
    [DataMember(Name = "json_name")]
```

like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class AuthToken 
{
    [DataMember(Name = ".expires")]
    public long expires_in { get; set; }
}
```

And if you want to set default values, use this:

```
    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        expires_in = blabla
    }
```

As you have a non-standard date format, you'll want to specify a serializer settings object in order to allow the datetimes to be processed.  If you're using .NET 4.5 or later, you can use:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AuthToken),
    new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify a default parsing format for the DateTime too?

Comment: no. i serialize datetimes to string and then convert to datetime. otherwise u get stupid exception from .net because of invalid date format.

Comment: @GlenH7 - In .Net 4.5 and above you can specify a `DateTime` format.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266435/datacontractjsonserializer-deserializing-datetime-within-listobject/22546727#22546727) relating to [`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.DateTimeFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.datetimeformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @dbc - Thanks for that link, that helped glue it all together.  I have edited that into my answer.